# Parse JSON in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file which has the below content. I want to iterate through each item (using foreach loop) in Powershell.
How can I do it?

```
{
  "abc": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "'167401'"
  },
  "dar": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "8980"
  },
  "hgt": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "893240"
  },
  "newvar1": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "newvalue1"
  },
  "var": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "1230"
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of powershell are you using?

Comment: PSVersion  :  5.1.19041.1682

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: Powershell 7 has name, value pairs with `convertfrom-json -AsHashtable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$input = @'
<your input here>
'@

$json = $input | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($item in $json.PSObject.Properties)
{
    Write-Output $item.Name 
    Write-Output $item.Value.isSecret
    Write-Output $item.Value.value
}
```

with your input, this gives me:

```
abc
'167401'
dar
8980
hgt
893240
newvar1
newvalue1
var
1230
```

as all your `isSecret` values are null they don't show any content.

Comment: I want to fetch "*.isSecret" and "*.value" for each item. Is there any way ?

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it gives the illusion of iterating over the members of the root object, but it doesn't actually

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen fair, I've just realised that the input is an object rather than a list. will update.

Comment: Anyway, your answer satisfies my requirements. Thank you so much @TZHX .

Answer (score 1):

```
$Data = $Json |ConvertFrom-Json
$Data.PSObject.Properties.Value

isSecret value
-------- -----
         '167401'
         8980
         893240
         newvalue1
         1230
```

To iterate through the values:

```
$Data.PSObject.Properties.Value.ForEach{
    Write-Host 'isSecret:' $_.isSecret
    Write-Host 'Value:' $_.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7 version with name,value pairs:

```
cat file.json | convertfrom-json -AsHashtable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
hgt                            {isSecret, value}
newvar1                        {isSecret, value}
dar                            {isSecret, value}
abc                            {isSecret, value}
var                            {isSecret, value}
```